# MAUI Picker set SelectedItem

Tags: picker, maui, selecteditem

In MAUI I need to populate a picker (combobox) with currencies.

These currencies come from a json with a structure like this:

```
  {
    "code": "USD",
    "decimal_digits": 2,
    "name": "US Dollar",
    "name_plural": "US dollars",
    "rounding": 0,
    "symbol": "$",
    "symbol_native": "$"
  },
  {
    "code": "EUR",
    "decimal_digits": 2,
    "name": "Euro",
    "name_plural": "euros",
    "rounding": 0,
    "symbol": "\u20AC",
    "symbol_native": "\u20AC"
  }
```

In the view I have the picker defined as (snip):

```
<Picker
    ItemsSource ="{Binding Currencies, Mode=TwoWay}"
    ItemDisplayBinding ="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource CurrencyPickerConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding Expense.Currency}">
</Picker>
```

The CurrencyPickerConverter class looks like this:

```
public class CurrencyPickerConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
            //Go from the currency to "symbol [name]":
            Currency model = value as Currency;
            return $"{model.symbol} [{model.name}]";
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            //Go from "symbol [name]" to the currency:
            return Commons.Currencies.Where(x => x.symbol.Equals((value as string).Split(' ')[0]));
        }
}
```

The Expense.Currency property in the viewmodel will only contain the Symbol i.e. "EUR" or "$"

The problem is this: the picker loads the "Currencies" list of Currency objects, like so:

```
  {
    "code": "USD",
    "decimal_digits": 2,
    "name": "US Dollar",
    "name_plural": "US dollars",
    "rounding": 0,
    "symbol": "$",
    "symbol_native": "$"
  }
```

and shows the string "$ [US Dollar]" thanks to the CurrencyPickerConverter.

Great.

On selected item changed I have transformed "$ [US Dollar]" to a currency and then selected only the symbol like so:

```
private void PickerCurrency_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Picker currencyPicker = (Picker)sender;
            int selectedIndex = currencyPicker.SelectedIndex;

            if (selectedIndex != -1)
            {
                Currency selectedCurrency = currencyPicker.SelectedItem as Currency;
                lblSelectedCurrency.Text = selectedCurrency.symbol;
            }
        }
```

When viewing the expense I would need to select the corresponding currency, of course.
For example, if my viewmodel has the property Expense.Currency = "$", I would like to see the picker set to the Dollar currency value, and therefore should show the string  "$ [US Dollar]" thanks to the CurrencyPickerConverter class.

So my questions are:

1. How should I set the properties ItemsSource, ItemDisplayBinding, and SelectedItem to make it work properly ?
2. Also, my ConvertBack method is not get called at all ! Why ?

Thank you
Alex

Comment: I’m not clear on what the problem is.  You say the Picker is displaying the data formatted the way you want.

Comment: Hello, Jason. Yes, the picker is indeed displaying the data the way I want it. My problem is when binding the selected item value (if the bound value comes from the ViewModel as "$", for instance, I would like the picker to set itself on the "dollar" currency item (see the Currency model above), so I can see the string "$ [US Dollar]" displayed in the picker.  In other words, the picker is bound to ObservableCollection<Currency>, and I'd like the SelectedItem to be bound to Expense.Currency, where this is "$", and to show "$ [US Dollar]". Thank you very much, Jason !

Comment: The SelectedItem must be a member of ItemsSource so what you’re doing won’t work.  However you can use SelectedIndexChanged like you’re already doing to manually set that property.

Comment: You can check the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/picker/populating-itemssource) and the [sample](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/main/UserInterface/MonkeyAppPicker). It described in detail how to set the properties ItemsSource, ItemDisplayBinding, and SelectedItem to make it work properly.